# FFT Code Break Down

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, fft, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to implement the FFT in one of my projects. Unfortunately I feel like every site I go to is explaining things way over my head. I have looked at many different sites for clarification but alas it has so far eluded me.

Each of the sites that I have so far went to has either had the code written well with no comments on the variables or other explanation or has explained things at such a level that I cannot grasp it.

I would appreciate it if someone can break down each part of this code and the process in the most descriptive way possible.

First, I know that the input to the FFT is [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]. What do these numbers represent? Are they in hertz or volts?

Last, I know that the output from the FFT is 4.000 2.613 0.000 1.082 0.000 1.082 0.000 2.613. What do these numbers represent? What is the unit? How can they be used to get the magnitude or frequency from the data set?

Again, I am looking for every step to be explained, so commenting the following FFT code would also be very helpful. I would be eternally grateful if you can explain this well enough that a 5 year old would understand. (I feel about that age sometimes when looking at the articles).

Thanks for all the help in advance. You guys on here have helped me out a TON.

CODE SOURCE: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Python

CODE:

```
from cmath import exp, pi

def fft(x):
    # I understand that we are taking the length of the array sent
    #   into the function and assigning it to N. But I do not get why.
    N = len(x)
    # I get that we are returning itself if it is the only item. 
    # What does x represent at this point?
    if N <= 1: return x
    # We are creating an even variable and assigning it to the fft of 
    #   the even terms of x. This is possibly because we can use this 
    #   to take advantage of the symmetry? 
    even = fft(x[0::2])
    # We are now doing the same thing with the odd variable. It is 
    #   going to be the fft of the odd terms of x. Why would we need
    #   both if we are using it to take advantage of the symmetry?
    odd =  fft(x[1::2])
    T= [exp(-2j*pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
    return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N//2)] + \
           [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N//2)]
# I understand that we are printing a join formatted as a float
# I get that the float will have 3 numbers after the decimal place and
#    will take up a total of 5 spots
# I also understand that the abs(f) is what is being formatted and
#    that the absolute value is getting rid of the imaginary portion
#    that is often seen returned by the FFT
print( ' '.join("%5.3f" % abs(f) 
            for f in fft([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])) )
```

RETURNS:

```
4.000 2.613 0.000 1.082 0.000 1.082 0.000 2.613
```

Comment: This may help you better understand the algorithm and its implementation: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/28/understanding-the-fft/

Comment: This will help with understanding some of the variable values. If I find more I will write an actually useful answer.

http://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/

Comment: This will help understand the DFT. I think I will be able to give a helpful answer after applying what is taught here to your problem.

http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/intuitive-guide-discrete-fourier-transform/

Comment: Very good articles. I have looked into all three of them and they are giving me a better grasp on what the FFT and DFT is. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

An FFT is just a fast way to calculate of a DFT (using a factoring trick).

Perhaps learn what a DFT does first, as the FFT factoring trick might be confusing the issue of what a DFT does.  A DFT is just a basis transform (a type of matrix multiply).  The units can be completely arbitrary (milliVolts, inches, gallons, dollars, etc.)   And any set of frequency results depends on a sample rate of the input data.

Comment: Are the units maintained both in and out of the fft? If he put hz into it, would he get hz out?

Comment: So.. from what I'm reading.. Yes? If so, a simple yes would do.

Comment: It seems that you are correct. After I have looked into it more I see that as long as I correctly understand the DFT I will be able to get a hold of the FFT. It would have been helpful to have a short overview of the DFT or a link to where I can find a simple explanation, but @TysonGraham has given me a good link above. Thank you for your time and effort.